# characteristic vs minimal polynomial

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $L$ be a finite field extension of $K$. For every element $\theta$ in $L$ define the characteristic polynomial of $\theta$ as follows
$$\operatorname{char}_{\theta}(X):=\det(X\cdot id_L-r_\theta)$$
where $r_{\theta}$ is the $K$-linear map given by
$$r_{\theta}:L\longrightarrow L\qquad;\qquad x\longmapsto x\theta$$

Let finally $f(X)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\theta$ over $K$.

My question is: $\operatorname{char}_{\theta}=f?$

Comment: The degree of the characteristic polynomial is always the degree of the field extension, i.e, $[L:K]$. Now, what is the degree of a minimal polynomial of an element in $K$?

Comment: @JiangweiXue less than the degree of the extension?

Comment: Not necessarily, @FedericaMaggioni: I'd say that *at most* the extension's degree.

Comment: @DonAntonio so i can only say that minimal divides characteristic?

Comment: Indeed so, @FedericaMaggioni: that's always true, but many times they both can be the same.

Comment: Here is an example: Take $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})$ and $K=\mathbb{Q}$.  What is the minimal polynomial of $\theta=1$? More generally, can you say something about the degree of the minimal polynomial and the extension $K(\theta)/K$?

Comment: @JiangweiXue when the extension $L$ over $K$ is simple of degree $n$, i.e. $L=K[\theta]$, then the minimal polynomial of $\theta$ has degree $n$, in this case minimal=characteristic

Comment: @FedericaMaggioni Yes, but only for primitive elements $θ$ for that extension and not any element of a simple extension needs to be primitive. In fact, for $θ ∈ L/K$ in an algebraic extension $χ_\textrm{min}(θ) = χ_\textrm{char}(θ)$ if and only if $L = K(θ)$. To see this, note $χ_\textrm{min}(θ) \mid χ_\textrm{char}(θ)$, $K(θ) ⊂ L$ and $\deg (χ_\textrm{min}(θ)) = [K(θ) : K]$ and $\deg(χ_\textrm{char}(θ)) = [L:K]$, as already pointed out by JiangweiXue and DonAntonio. So both polynomials are the same if and only if $[L : K(θ)] = 1$. (Did I say something new at all? That was redundant of me.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is true iff $L = K[\theta]$ by examining degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $d = [L : K(\theta)]$. Then $\chi_{char(\theta)}(x) = \chi_{min(\theta)}(x)^d$ assuming we've normalized both polynomials to be monic.